# Simple question regarding Symbols in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symbols

I am new to rails and have a very simple question but couldnt find answer on the web, hope one of you could help me.

I have a form with following code

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :address_street %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_street %>
  </p>
<p>
<%= f.label :address_city %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_city %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :address_state %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_state %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :address_country %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address_country %>
  </p>
```

what I want to do is use geocoder to get the value of latitude nad longitude.

the geocoder function is someting like this on  _geocodeby :address

since I get :address as multiple symbols I want to add them before passing to geocoder. Since addition doesnt work on symbol, how could I accomplish.

Thanks,
Venkatesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an `address` method on your model like this

```
def address
  "#{address_street} #{address_city} #{address_state} #{address_country}"
end
```

and use geocoder to geocode `:address`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain why this works for a better understanding of symbols ? what does a symbol relate to in Java ? I am trying to understand how symbols are used in rails. May be this is a large topic to disucss, it would be great if you could point to some resource for better understanding aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great blog post explaining Ruby symbols: [The Difference Between Ruby Symbols and Strings](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

And here is a detailed guide: [The Ruby_Newbie Guide to Symbols](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm)